# WebAsyncRefreshPanel vs Ajax UpdatePanel

Tags: ajax, updatepanel

Is there an advantage to using the Infragistics netadvantage WebAsyncRefreshPanel vs the Ajax UpdatePanel? or vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what controls you're using.
You may refer here on the difference of both controls: http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/t/17538.aspx